# Changing in-text cite

Tags: citing, natbib

```
\documentclass[twoside, a4paper, 10pt]{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\begin{document}

we follow the selection criteria proposed by \cite{feem}

\bibliographystyle{apa-good}
\bibliography{bibliography}

\end{document}
```

In my bibliography bibtex file I have this entry:

```
@misc{feem,
    author  = "{Monitor Group-Fondazione Eni Enrico Mattei (FEEM)}",
    title   = "{``Weathering the Storm: Sovereign Wealth Funds in the Global Economic Crisis of 2008''}",
    year    = "2009",
    howpublished = "William F. Miracky and Bernardo Bortolotti, eds. (Monitor Group)",}
```

Which results in the following output:

[image]

However, I would like to change the output to:

[image]

That is, I want to keep the author details in the bibliography entry as Monitor 'Group-Fondazione Eni Enrico Mattei (FEEM)' however I just want to change how it's cited in-text. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a cite alias with `natbib` package, using the `\defcitealias` command, which allows you to refer to a reference (Monitor Group..., in this case) with an alias name (Monitor Group-FEEM) while still maintaining how the bib entry looks.

You would have to change how you `\cite`, though. Use `\citetalias{<key>}` in order to access this.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
    @misc{feem,
        author  = "{Monitor Group-Fondazione Eni Enrico Mattei (FEEM)}",
        title   = "{``Weathering the Storm: Sovereign Wealth Funds in the Global Economic Crisis of 2008''}",
        year    = "2009",
        howpublished = "William F. Miracky and Bernardo Bortolotti, eds. (Monitor Group)",}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[twoside, a4paper, 10pt]{article}
\usepackage{natbib}

\defcitealias{feem}{Monitor Group-FEEM~\citeyearpar{feem}}% <--------------

\begin{document}

we follow the selection criteria proposed by \citetalias{feem}% <--------

\bibliographystyle{apa}% I don't have apa-good.bst
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

[image]